# let variable in angular ngif with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, angular, angular13

In Angular (13) is there a way to assign the result of a function to a variable (in the `.html` part of a component, **not** *template*) having **multiple conditions** in *ngIf*

```
<div *ngIf="let getMyVar() as myVar && isVisible && isClean">
    {{ 'this is myVar: ' + myVar }}
</div>
```

if not what workaround is possible to implement?

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 edited OP do not mention templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did not find anything better than splitting the `ngIf` in two

```
<ng-container *ngIf="getMyVar(); let myVar">
    <div *ngIf="isVisible && isClean">
        {{ 'this is myVar: ' + myVar }}
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 5):

The conditionals seem to use standard Javascript operator logic:

[Mozilla documentation for the Logical AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) states the following:

> ...the operator returns the value of the first falsy operand encountered when evaluating from left to right, or the value of the last operand if they are all truthy.

As such, the following works:

```
<div *ngIf="isVisible && isClean && getMyVar(); let myVar">
    {{ 'this is myVar: ' + myVar }}
</div>
```

I tested this locally, and it was successful at displaying the value of `getMyVar()`

Answer (score -1):

Not that good but might be an idea.

```
<ng-template #template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" let-myVar="key1" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ key1: getMyVar() }">
  <div *ngIf="myVar && isVisible && isClean">
    {{ 'this is myVar: ' + myVar }}
  </div>
</ng-template>
```